# How call procedure inside in another procedure in Oracle, Sql Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ShowShips3Task(
       p_Register IN ship.registry_country%TYPE,
       o_name OUT ship.ship_name%TYPE,
       o_capitan OUT  ship.captain_name%TYPE)
IS
   procedure showshipsDisp(
    o_cap out Ship.captain_name%type,
    o_dis out Ship.displacement%type)
    is
    begin
    Select Captain_name, Displacement
    into o_cap, o_dis
    from Ship Where Ship_name = 'Avrora';
    end;

BEGIN

  SELECT Ship_name , Captain_Name
  INTO o_name, o_capitan
  from  Ship WHERE registry_country LIKE p_register || '%';

END;
```

how execute one Procedure inside another in same time?

and how can i create multivalued paramater, means that second proceduru inside depend on paramatr of first procedure?

Comment: Just call it like any other PL/SQL procedure. You can use `o_name` and `o_capitan` as an input parameters for the procedure `showshipsDisp`.

Comment: Try it, but it's call only First not that inside

Comment: Can you please show us what have you tried? Example doesn't shows where do you want to call the nested procedure.

Comment: I try call one procedure inside another. Procedure is created but when i call it, it's call only first, second is ignored that is inside.

Comment: In the asked question you are not calling the nested procedure, you are only declaring it. The call has to be between the `BEGIN` and `END` statements.

Answer (score 1):

In the example from the question nested procedure is only declared but never called. To run the nested procedure the call has to be present between `BEGIN` and `END` statements:

```
BEGIN

  SELECT Ship_name , Captain_Name
  INTO o_name, o_capitan
  from  Ship WHERE registry_country LIKE p_register || '%';

  showshipsDisp(o_cap => ?
               ,o_dis => ?);

END;
```

Question marks should be replaced by proper variables.

Comment: How It execute? I try it in procedure settings in sql Developer, but same.